# How to loop over an array and be sure to get enough gas?

Tags: solidity

in my contract a function loop over an array with undefined length :

```
function tallyVotes() external onlyOwner {
        uint _winningProposalId;
        for (uint256 p = 0; p < proposalsArray.length; p++) {
            if (proposalsArray[p].voteCount > proposalsArray[_winningProposalId].voteCount) {
                _winningProposalId = p;
            }
        }
        winningProposalID = _winningProposalId;
    }
```

Here it's okay the array length is under 100 but if length would have been more than 100 000 000 ( I overdo it I know) I will be out of gas !
So my question is how to handle this ? Is there a better way to loop over an array if I can't be sure I will get enough gas ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

- Make `tallyVotes()` accept a range so it is possible to call it several times. It would need to  keep around the state of the tally between calls.
- Keep an index into the proposals sorted by the vote count. For example using a heap structure to keep the index updated after each vote. Then `tallyVotes` job is distributed to every vote received.

Perhaps it should be considered having a limit on the proposals, or having two rounds the first round requires certain threshold to participate in the second round.